# Is there a FluentAssertions Should for checking an XML document versus an expected document?

Tags: fluent-assertions

Is there a FluentAssertions "Should.Be" for checking an entire XML document versus an expected document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `xDocument.BeEquivalentTo(otherxDocument)` to a deep comparison. See the [definition[(https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/blob/master/Src/FluentAssertions/Xml/XDocumentAssertions.cs#L116 ) from the source code.

Comment: Excellent ... thanks for the pointer, and many many thanks for FluentAssertions !!